# How to load different HTML based on window.width()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to always listen to `window.width()` and load different HTML codes based on the width values? I'm using `window.width()` and `replaceWith()`.

It's only works when I open the page and not working when I resizing my browser window.

My code inside my html file:

```
    var width;
    $(window).resize(function() {
        width = $(window).width();
        if (width < 768) {
            $("#the_dropdown").replaceWith("<p>Less than 768</p>");
        } else {
            $("#the_dropdown").replaceWith("<p> More than 768</p>");
        }
    });
    $(window).trigger('resize');
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/b9ytss4L/)

Another question, does `replaceWith()` suitable for situation that involves long HTML codes (more than 1 line)?

I've already done some sets of HTML codes based on specific window's width and I want to put it accordingly inside my `#the_dropdown` div.

Comment: It's possible in CSS with `@media` queries : http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: As ceadreak mentions, you should use media queries or perhaps something like modernizr to detect and react.

Comment: That one is to change CSS based on window's width. I already know about that. I'm not changing my CSS. I'm changing my HTML based on specific window's width.

Comment: Just to give you a term to search. What you are asking for is `responsive design`.

Comment: Don't check window width, use instead `window.matchMedia` and any polyfill to support older browsers if needed  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.matchMedia

Comment: Media queries aren't appropriate here, as content is changing and not layout or styles.

Comment: isherwood is correct here.

Comment: Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b9ytss4L

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because `replaceWith()` replaces the selected element. In your case, the element with id #the_dropdown. Therefore on the next trigger, this element isn't found and no text is written.

Replace `replaceWith()` with `.html()`.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/b9ytss4L/1/)

Comment: So the OP should just be calling ` $("#the_dropdown").html("<p>Less than 768</p>")`